# How to connect to a guest VM from the host system?

Tags: virtualbox

I have a VM webserver setup and I have installed and started Apache.  The VM has a bridged network interface and can be pinged from the host using 192.168.0.2.

However, if I type that same IP address into the browser on the host machine, I was expecting to see the default apache page generated on the VM, but instead, I get `can't connect to 192.168.0.2` in the host machines browser.

I've clearly missed something out.  Anyone know what I have missed or done wrong?

Output from VM `netstat -tnlp`

```
tcp     0     0 0.0.0.0:22        0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN     950/sshd
tcp     0     0 127.0.0.1:25      0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN    1026/master
tcp     0     0 :::22                  :::*     LISTEN     904/sshd
tcp     0     0 ::1:25                 :::*     LISTEN     980/master
```

Rough drawing of what I'm thinking the network activity/connectivity would look like.

[image]

Comment: If you see only `:::80`, then Apache is only listening for IPv6 connections. Have you tried checked your `Listen` directives?

Comment: Try adding the `-p` flag to `netstat` to verify that you Apache is actually listening on port 80, and not some other service. Can you run `curl localhost` from the guest? What does `grep -C3 -rni Listen /etc/httpd/` show?

Comment: Do me a favor, if these directions work, write that up as an answer, since you'll have access to the screenshots. This question comes up a fair amount, I don't believe its solution's been accurately captured.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Issue #1 - VM networking types

There are 3 modes of networking:

1. NAT
2. Host Only
3. Bridged

#### Details on setting them up

- This AU  Q&A titled: "[In VirtualBox, how do I set up host-only virtual machines that can access the Internet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293816/in-virtualbox-how-do-i-set-up-host-only-virtual-machines-that-can-access-the-in)", shows how to do #2.
- This article titled: "[How to Setup VirtualBox Guest Additions and Network](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/virtualbox-guest-additions/)", shows how to do #3.

#### When to use each?

- **#1**: For development of Facebook/web apps that are on other servers
- **#2**: If you want to build your own app, and test it from the VirtualBox host (not just the guest VM)
- **#3**: If you want to build an app and test it from other systems on LAN

### Issue #2 - firewall blocking?

Depending on which distro you're using, the firewall might be blocking your web browser from accessing your Apache instance. This would make sense given you're able to ping the system, but not access it via port 80, which is the port that Apache is listening on.

#### temporarily disabling it

On CentOS you use this command to disable it.

```
$ /etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

#### check that Apache's listening

You can also confirm that it's listening on this port.

```
$ netstat -antp | grep :80 | head -1 | column -t
tcp  0  0  :::80  :::*  LISTEN  3790/httpd
```

#### confirm firewall's off

The firewall can be confirmed that it's wide open.

```
$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

If this solves your issue then you can permanently add a rule that allows traffic in via TCP port 80.

#### adding a rule for TCP port 80

```
$ /etc/init.d/iptables restart
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$ /etc/init.d/iptables save
```

**NOTE:** This will make the rule persist between reboots.

#### firewall is accepting TCP port 80

A system that has the port 80 open would look something like this:

```
$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:8834 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

### Issue #3 - Apache listening?

In the above issue we saw that Apache was listening, but sometimes it's mis-configured so that it's only listening on 1 IP address, or that it's listening on a different network interface. The command `netstat` can be used to double check this as well as reviewing the Apache configuration files.

```
$ netstat -anpt | grep :80 | column -t
tcp  0  0  0.0.0.0:80  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  1750/httpd
```

This shows that Apache is listening on all interfaces (IP 0.0.0.0).

I won't repeat what @[Lekensteyn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108879/7453)'s answer which covers this particular issue in more details here.

#### References

- [Chapter 6. Virtual networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)

Comment: now I'm completely confused.  I've already got the VM in bridged mode, I can ping the VM from the host but I can't get to the same IP address from the web browser on the host even though the VM has apache installed and started, I should see the `it worked!` apache page.

Comment: @oshirowanen - thanks for not getting frustrated as we try and resolve the issue 8-). Make sure Apache is running on CentOS, `/etc/init.d/httpd status`, should show running.

Comment: I stopped the firewall on the VM and I can now see the default IP page when using a web browser on the host machine to access the url of the VM!!!

Comment: @oshirowanen - WOOHOO! OK so the whole issue was just the firewall, I'll add a command to add the rule to your firewall, you can also make it permanent w/ this command, `/sbin/service iptables save`.

Comment: Yes!  I did a minimal install of CentOS and I shouldn't have assumed that the firewall was disabled by default...  To be honest, the firewall didn't even come to my mind.  Thanks for spending your time to help.

Comment: @oshirowanen - your welcome, glad your issue's been resolved. Please mark this answer as accepted so that other's know your issue's been resolved. Also please delete any comments above that are no longer pertinent.

Answer (score 4):

On CentOS 7, firewalld has replaced iptables as the default firewall.

I had to use

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

to pause the firewall to test the connection from host to CentOS VM.

See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756240/how-can-i-use-iptables-on-centos-7

Answer (score 2):

Your Apache installation is likely configured to listen on localhost only. You can verify that by running in your guest:

```
$ netstat -tnl | grep :80
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address      Foreign Address  State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80         0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80              :::*             LISTEN
```

If it says `0.0.0.0:80`, it listens on all interfaces. In your case, I would expect `127.0.0.1:80` instead. To solve this, edit your Apache config (somewhere in `/etc/httpd/conf/`) and change:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

to:

```
Listen 80
```

You can also use `nmap` to verify the available services on your machine. It should look like:

```
$ nmap 192.168.0.2

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-01-11 15:22 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (192.168.0.2)
Host is up (0.0036s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.21 seconds
```