# VirtualBox guest machine as a nginx host

Tags: networking, fedora, virtualbox, nginx

I have VirtualBox 4.3.12 with Fedora 20 and nginx 1.4.7 installed. Machine has Bridged Network interface and pings can be done both ways:
from host machine (Windows 7) using

`ping 192.168.0.15` (virtual machine's ip address)

and from guest machine

`ping 192.168.0.10` (host machine ip address)

but what i can't do is access guest machine's nginx from host machine. I have read [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/virtualbox-guest-additions/) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108878/how-to-connect-to-a-guest-vm-from-the-host-system) and have done as those articles / previously asked question told me to, but i still can't manage to view nginx site from host machine.

`netstat -tnlp` returns:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN        930/nginx: master p
```

Comment: Firewall allowing port 80 access to guest's IP?

Comment: Does Virtualbox reserve port 80 for anything?

Comment: Yes, firewall on Windows was allowing port 80 to access guest's IP. And @Suchipi: it didn't, but it is working now, i had to add new entry to iptables: iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT, and it is all working now, thank you guys!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes, @Nate, All i had to do was: iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT in VM's console.

Comment: didn't work for me :( (also you should make it an answer if it worked for you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I did:

```
iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

I got an error of:

```
iptables: Index of insertion too big.
```

The reason is that I do not have any policies in place and so the "INPUT 4" part is trying to insert at index 4 when it should be index = 1. To view your rules do:

```
sudo iptables --list-rules
```

Then insert at the appropriate index. (In most cases):

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

This finally got it to work!

> - My virtualbox settings are:
>
>   - host port 8080,
>   - guest IP 10.0.2.15
>   - guest port 80

nginx conf file is:

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

in VM's console and it worked.